# Ubuntu 19 all apps not showing up

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, menu, ubuntu-dock, appmenu

All apps aren't showing up as Ubuntu 18 on Ubuntu 19 (when clicked left-bottom menu button on Ubuntu dock). But if searched searched apps are showing. Is there any fix for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch from '**Frequent**' to '**All**' by clicking the button at the bottom of Application overview:

[image]